# Git submodules checkout to branch if not exist then switch to another

Tags: bash, git, git-submodules

I would like to have something like:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive git checkout some_feature_branch || git checkout develop
```

so if `some_feature_branch` exists then I want to checkout it otherwise `develop`. Is it possible to implement that with built-in `git` or `bash` commands?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember that `git submodule foreach` passes its argument to a shell, so all you have to do is provide the right shell commands.  But if you type a command *into* a shell (command line interpreter), the *shell* decides what you meant.  The command:

```
foo some bars || raz a matazz
```

*means*, to the shell:

1. try to foo some bars
2. if that succeeds, stop; otherwise, try to raz a matazz

That's not what you want here.  You want `git submodule` *itself* to try to `git checkout` and if that fails, you want `git submodule`—not your main shell—to go on to `git checkout`.  That is, you don't want:

1. for all submodules, try a git checkout
2. if that succeeds, stop; otherwise try one git checkout

You want:

1. for all submodules:

   - try a git checkout
   - if that succeeds, go on to the next submodule; if it fails, try another git checkout, and *then* go on to the next submodule

So that's:

```
git submodule foreach "git checkout a || git checkout b"
```

The double quotes here (though single quotes would also work) *protect* the `||` so that the top level *shell* doesn't try to interpret this as:

```
(git submodule foreach git checkout a) || (git checkout b)
```

Instead, the top level shell passes the entire "git checkout a || git checkout b" part to the `git submodule foreach` command.  That command—the `git submodule foreach`—then passes the `git checkout a || git checkout b` on to one command-line-interpreter run for *one submodule*.  Then `git submodule foreach` goes on to the next submodule.

(Note that this has very little to do with Git itself: it's basic *shell* programming.  The shell is an interpreter that runs shell programs, and you need to learn to write programs for it.)

Comment: What an answer!